# How are competing design standards merged for joint-agency or transnational projects?

Tags: logo, branding, history

Reading through the [NASA Graphics Standards Manual](https://www.nasa.gov/sites/default/files/atoms/files/nasa_graphics_manual_nhb_1430-2_jan_1976.pdf), pages 7.9–11 inform how the iconic worm logo and other graphical elements are to be used on flight-ready vehicles, whether aircraft, spacecraft, or mission payloads. However, it does not mention how to use competing but equally-important elements such as the logos of other space agencies or nations.

For examples of such joint projects, consider the [Orion ESM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orion_service_module#ATV-based_module), developed by the ESA, (although it predates the graphics-standards manual), the [definitely-never-going-to-happen joint moon mission JFK proposed briefly](https://www.history.com/this-day-in-history/kennedy-proposes-joint-mission-to-the-moon), or the fictional [joint Iris probe](http://www.spacenewsmag.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/The-Martian-IRIS-photo.jpg) in the Martian.

The manual makes it clear that the NASA logo is be the dominant design element unless the US flag is present. How would the authors of the manual recommend dealing with competing design ethics and elements on joint missions (not to mention the bizarre aspect ratio of the US flag compared to nearly any other flag)?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this will answer your question or not.... I'm uncertain if *anyone* here who is not directly affiliated with NASA or the joint agency *could* provide any answer.

---

In the past I've worked for the Department of the Army. Not quite NASA, but similar.

When joint ventures were undertaken or corporate sponsorship was involved, there was an office which was the focal point of the "deal" or "collaboration". This office directed the priority of branding to the marketing department. Often it was the "Office of Corporate Affairs" or "Department of Public and Consumer Affairs".

One still had to adhere to all the general brand guidelines for each and every brand/agencies. However, one brand was either given priority (made larger and more prominent) or multiple brands were all to be treated as equals - which was a design nightmare at times.

The manuals or brand guidelines for *each* agency are important for usage, but when there are multiple agencies all to be used, it requires direction as to *which* agency, if any, is to be given "top billing". No manual or brand guideline is going to detail joint venture usage.